# zum Abendessen vs für das Abendessen

Tags: difference, word-choice, preposition

When I use in a sentence "zum Abendessen" and "für das Abendessen"?
I know they are both correct, but I could not find what is the difference.

> Ich gehe etwas für das Abendessen einkaufen.
>
> Ich kaufe Hähnchem zum Abendessen.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first example sounds more as if you're going to buy ingredients to prepare dinner, the second one, "Ich kaufe Hähnchen zum Abendessen.", might be either Hähnchen as an ingredient to prepare or a ready-to-eat one from "Chicken 4 U".

If you say "Ich gehe Hähnchen für das Abendessen einkaufen." I'd definitely expect you coming home from the supermarket with an unprepared one and not with a "Chicken 4 you" bag.

Comment: I think this answer pretty much hits the point. With the "zum" you kind of describe the main part of the meal, while "für das" can also refer to any ingredient.